# Can I use managed C# DLL in unmanaged Delphi EXE?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, unmanaged, managed

Can I use managed C# DLL in unmanaged Delphi EXE? Or the only way is to have managed DLL and EXE or unmanaged DLL and EXE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few options, including at least the following:

1. Expose the classes that you need via COM which can be readily consumed by Delphi.
2. Create a mixed mode C++/CLI wrapper that uses the C# DLL as a reference. That mixed mode DLL can export native functions and you can then consume that DLL using Delphi `external`. That is, you consume the DLL just in the same way as Windows system DLLs are consumed.
3. Use Robert Giesecke's [UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).
4. Use the CLR's native API to consume the C# DLL directly. This option is probably the least attractive since it's the hardest to get right.

Comment: Do not forget http://www.remobjects.com/hydra and http://interop.managed-vcl.com/netinterop_csharp.php

Comment: This link provides some more information about different options: http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2015/04/30/introduction-to-the-xinterop-net-bridge/